# Jtable "listaction" url always calling action controller with old parameters value MVC4 Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-jtable

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult StudentList(int id= 0, int id2= 0)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get data from database

            List<Student> students = _repository.StudentRepository.GetStudents(id,id2);

            //Return result to jTable
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = students},JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message },JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My jquery

```
  $("#DDL_id").change(function(){ 
//fill dropdown2 "DDL_idd"  by ajax via get json call

});

 $("#DDL_idd").change(function(){ 

   var id= $("#DDL_id").val();
   var idd= $("#DDL_idd").val();

   var url = '/admin/StudentList?id1=' +id + '&id2='+idd;

 $('#General_InfoTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'General_Info List',
       actions: {
            listAction: url

        },
        fields: {
            RID: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: true,
                title: 'RID',
                width: '5%'
            },
            Quote: {
                title: 'Open Quote',
                list: true,
                width: '15%',


            },
            Customer_Name: {
                list: true,
                title: 'Customer',
                width: '25%'
            }

        }
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#General_InfoTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
 });
```

For first time I am getting correct id of both dropdowns in my controller  but after that if I change my selection from dropdown, my action did not getting new value and it executing with old value always  "StudentList(int id1= 0, int id2= 0)" id1 and id2 have old value and never reset again 
I have done with

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

and

```
 [Nocache]
```

on controller action and other solutions. Please Help.

Comment: Are u getting `id` and `idd` updated values in `$("#DDL_idd").change()` ?

Comment: yes i am getting every ID correctly but on the  "public JsonResult StudentList(int id= 0, int id2= 0)" i am getting old values is there something to do with httpPOST i mean i doing both getting and sending back to page is it correct way.   @abpatil

Comment: try to change default parameter `int id= 0, int id2= 0` to `int id, int id2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one variable scope / closures.

When the jTable options object is create and passed to the jTable constructor, whatever value was in url is fixed as the listAction.

It looks like you are trying to perform a "filter" operation

Just set the listAction to the static part of the url

```
listAction: '/admin/StudentList',
```

then when you populate the table

```
$('#General_InfoTableContainer').jtable('load',{
                                        'id1':$("#DDL_id").val(),
                                        'id2':$("#DDL_idd").val()});
```